# System.NotSupportedException while calling Setup() in Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq

I'm trying to setup method OnChange in IOptionsMonitor from asp.net core. But it is not obvious for me, why Setup() doesn't work. Btw I saw similar examples here [System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: p => (p.UserProfileId == 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502239/system-notsupportedexception-unsupported-expression-p-p-userprofileid-1) And I have allmost the same. What is the reason of error?

Execution code:

```
var optionMonitorMock = new Mock<IOptionsMonitor<MyConfig>>();

optionMonitorMock
    .Setup(mock => mock.OnChange(It.IsAny<Action<MyConfig>>()));
```

Code falls with exception:

> System.NotSupportedException.
>    Unsupported expression: mock => mock.OnChange< MyConfig>(It.IsAny< Action< MyConfig>>())
>   Extension methods (here: OptionsMonitorExtensions.OnChange) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

The asp.net's interface:

```
public interface IOptionsMonitor<out TOptions>
{
    TOptions CurrentValue { get; }
    TOptions Get(string name);
    IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener);
}
```

The model:

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is fairly self-explanatory? `OnChange(Action<MyConfig> config)` is an extension method (which you haven't posted). The only `OnChange` method on `IOptionsMonitor` has the signature `OnChange(Action <TOptions, string>)`, which is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface only exposes `IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener);` . Your exception says that

> Extension methods (here: OptionsMonitorExtensions.OnChange) may not be
>   used in setup / verification expressions.

So you are going to have to use Setup with that method.

```
optionMonitorMock
    .Setup(mock => mock.OnChange(It.IsAny<Action<MyConfig,string>>()));
```

Comment: Sure. I've tried to mock extension method. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this only works if the method `OnChange(Action<MyConfig, string>)` is being called on the mock.

Comment: But if ```OnChange(Action<MyConfig>)``` is called the extension method does call ```OnChange(Action<MyConfig, string>)``` and you can still use the mock for the same purpose.